# Same Application deployed in two different websphere 8 profiles share session?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-8

I have one application WAR. I have created two profiles AppSrv01, AppSrv02 on Websphere 8.0.0.0.

My application is having MQ connectivity, J2ee application on struts 1.1.

I have deployed WAR on both the server AppSrv01 as a context A and AppSrv02 as a context B.

I have session listener in my application which will take note of total available session.

The scenario is as given below....

Going and login to url localhost:9082/A, go to some page in it.

Going and login to url localhost:9082/B, go to some page in it in another tab of same browser.

Going to url localhost:9082/A, clicking on some of link or url from the existing page.

on remote debug from server when it come to SessionListener ... it shows below given stack

```
Daemon Thread [WebContainer : 10] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 24 in SessionCounterListener)) 
SessionCounterListener.sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent) line: 24    
WasHttpSessionObserver(HttpSessionObserver).sessionCreated(ISession) line: 111  
SessionEventDispatcher.sessionCreated(ISession) line: 98    
SessionManager.createISession(String, int, boolean) line: 268   
SessionManager.createSession(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, SessionAffinityContext, boolean) line: 640    
WsSessionContext(SessionContext).getIHttpSession(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean, boolean) line: 485   
WsSessionContext(SessionContext).getIHttpSession(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 419    
SRTRequestContext.getSession(boolean, WebApp) line: 104 
SRTServletRequest.getSession(boolean) line: 2099    
SRTServletRequest.getSession() line: 2083   
RequestProcessor.processLocale(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 631   
RequestProcessor.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 230 
ActionServlet.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1482   
ActionServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 525 
ActionServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 595   
ActionServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 668   
ServletWrapperImpl(ServletWrapper).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, WebAppServletInvocationEvent) line: 1147    
ServletWrapperImpl(ServletWrapper).handleRequest(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, WebAppDispatcherContext) line: 722    
ServletWrapperImpl(ServletWrapper).handleRequest(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 449 
ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 178 
WebAppFilterManagerImpl(WebAppFilterManager).invokeFilters(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, IServletContext, RequestProcessor, EnumSet<CollaboratorInvocationEnum>) line: 1020  
CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 87 
WSWebContainer(WebContainer).handleRequest(IRequest, IResponse) line: 883   
WSWebContainer.handleRequest(IRequest, IResponse) line: 1659    
WCChannelLink.ready(VirtualConnection) line: 195    
HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination() line: 452    
HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest() line: 511    
HttpInboundLink.processRequest() line: 305  
HttpInboundLink.ready(VirtualConnection) line: 276  
NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(VirtualConnection, TCPReadRequestContext, boolean) line: 214  
NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(VirtualConnection, TCPReadRequestContext) line: 113   
AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(IAbstractAsyncFuture, Object) line: 165   
AsyncFuture(AbstractAsyncFuture).invokeCallback(ICompletionListener, AbstractAsyncFuture, Object) line: 217 
AsyncFuture(AsyncChannelFuture).fireCompletionActions() line: 161   
AsyncFuture.completed(long) line: 138   
ResultHandler.complete(AsyncFuture, int, int) line: 204 
ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(boolean) line: 775 
ResultHandler$2.run() line: 905 
ThreadPool$Worker.run() line: 1648
```

It is creating another session instance. need to understand why it is creating another instance.

Comment: This will be awful hard to diagnose without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the tabs in IE, for IE its same session. So you will have only one cookie JSESSIONID per domain.

when you go to `localhost:9082/A` - you have `JSESSIONID` like `SESSIONID-A`.

when you go to `localhost:9082/B` - you have `JSESSIONID` like `SESSIONID-B`.

So when you access application on AppSrv01, `JSESSIONID` goes to AppSrv01 is `SESSIONID-B`. Appserver doesn't know about this session id, so it thinks its a new user and creates a session.

Try opening a IE-> File -> New Session and access the application on AppSrv02 you won't face the above issue.

If you have something like IEWATCH or Fidler, you will be able to see the `JSESSIONID` going from client/browser.

Comment: Thanks user2619241 and Christian Gärtner. It is working now I have also tried http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21225834

Answer (score 0):

There's also a setting `HttpSessionIdReuse` that *might* help with this as well. I know it works for multiple Servers in the same Cell, but I'm not sure whether it works across Profiles.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21210881